# Repository other than GitStack?

Tags: git, repository, gitstack

We use GitStack on our server as a git repository. Soon the free 30 day trial will be ended.
GitStack is nice and easy, but a bit too simple.

Before we start paying for it I wonder if there are some visual repository handler than you can set up on a windows server that has more features than GitStack?

We want to minimize the Git command line usage - be able to delete branch/file, clone repo, and so on from the website. We don't want to use GitHub and such as we want to have it all on our own server.

Answer (score 2):

[GitLab](http://gitlab.com/) is a pretty nice clone of GitHub which you can run on your own servers. Alternatively you can look at [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/).